# way to check both for alphabets and numeric charcters only

Tags: java, regex

I want to know if there is a way to check if a given string contains only combination of alphabets and numbers and nothing else.

for just alphanumeric i can use http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

for just numbers i can use Interger.parse or some regular expression.

But is there some library which does the combined check. I googled but didnt came across anything. Everywhere it's done separately.

Comment: `is there some library which does the combined check.` StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(String) does that only

Comment: Can you define what you mean by alphabets and numbers? Are characters like `ł` `ń` correct or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alphanumeric means "Only letters and/or digits"
`StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(String str)` does what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
someString.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]+")
```

Comment: Please explain *why* this is what OP needs to do; providing code changes without context or explanation helps no one.

Comment: Really? I think it inspires a bit of research

Answer (score 0):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

This will check numbers and alphabets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to match your `String`:

```
someString.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+");
```

This matches for at least one (`+`, if empty string is valid too, use `*` instead) character that can be either a digit from 0 to 9, or an uppercase or lowercase letter (no unicode letters, just A-Z).